# Can I give my Backtesting Strategy class multiple Dataframes?

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm stuck at this problem for a while now. In order to create two graphs I need to pass a dataframe into the strategy function from the backtesting library.

The problem with that is that my data is from two different sources, and the dates I use as indices do not allign. Because these diffenrent datasets are used for different graphs, I hoped to just pass both dataframes, but could'nt find a way.

I need the 'indi' column to be processed and tried passing it into/merging it with the second dataframe.

```
second['nlp'] = first['indi']
second = first.merge(second, on=first.index)
#either didn't work
```

Maybe you can help.

first dataframe:

```
                            Pos_Neg      indi
date                                         
2021-01-07 11:00:00+00:00  0.507565  0.866700
2021-01-26 19:00:00+00:00  0.471951  0.789079
```

second dataframe:

```
               Open     High      Low    Close    value
date                                                   
2021-01-08  1363.25  1383.75  1352.50  1372.50  1372.50
2021-01-11  1380.00  1387.50  1359.25  1372.25  1372.25
```